# In Apache Ignite, is there a way to @QuerySqlField work on optional types?

Tags: scala, ignite

Currently, optional types (e.g. `Option[String]`) annotated with `@QuerySqlField` result in a column of type `OTHER` in Ignite DB. Is there a way to unwrap the underlying `String` as a value instead?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is supported out of box. Maybe you could make it work by implementing `Binarylisable` and specifically handling such fields. Or some other marshaller tricks.